# Missing trunk folder in SVN or just hidden?

Tags: svn

I created a local repository in my other Desktop and it looks fine because I can export it commit and update. But my problem is when I checked the folder in where did I create my repository the trunk folder is missing. I checked if it is hidden but still no folder.

When I checked my repo-browser, I can access my file. I need to open my files in the trunk so that I can upload it to my hosting server.

Comment: "the trunk folder is missing" - when you created new repository, did you create a trunk folder inside it? If you haven't, you can do so. It is not mandatory to have trunk/branches/tags folders, it is just convention.

Comment: I didn't created it yet. If I create a trunk folder in my repository the next step is to export my files in that directory?

Comment: Actually, after you create trunk folder in your repo, you will import your files in there. If you are using TortoiseSVN, right click to your local copy folder -> TorotiseSVN -> Import...

Answer (score 3):

The basic folders trunk, tags and branches are not automatically created when you initialize a svn repository (e.g they are not mandatory, they just became a standard).

you have to create those folder with the `svn mkdir <folder>` command. If you are using tortoise you can just create those folder within tortoise easily.

Here is a step by step todolist :

- Create the repository
- Create the folders trunk / tags / branches
- Checkout the trunk
- Do whatever you want in your local folder
- Commit the changes

This is a very simple way of using svn. For more advance usage you can check the [svn book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.pdf) (which is quite bit though) :

Comment: Thanks for your answer but where the svn put my imported files? And I am using tortoisesvn. How can I created those commands?